# Mathematical Induction Proofs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

I've really been struggling with mathematical induction. I've been trying to follow my book the best I can. I feel like my proofs are correct. But then again I have my doubts. If anyone can give me some insight on weather I am doing it correctly or not that would be awesome.

[image]

I don't want these answered for me I just want some good feedback.

Comment: Those are fine. However, if you're writing them up for an introductory class, they might have a specific template they want you to follow. E.g. some require writing "Let $P(k)$ be the statement that ..." and "Since $P(1)$ is true, and $P(k)$ is true implies $P(k+1)$ is true, hence by mathematical induction ...."

Comment: @calvinLin Thank you for the feedback I really appreciate it. Also what you said does make sense to me. This is my first class where I have to write proofs so its very new to me. I guess you could say it is an intro class since the next class I will have to take that is similar to this is algorithms. I am carious are you saying that my answer to these proofs is something you would expect to see in a higher up course? Or is it simply lacking in information that could make it better?

Comment: @Davidsmith This is exactly what I would expect to see unless the instructor provided further instructions. It's clearly presented and you have organized your thoughts and calculations well.

Comment: It's more a comment about the education system, where "if you do not follow the rules, you do not get the points". Your solution as written is clear and would be understood by other mathematicians.

Comment: @CalvinLin: It is clear that you are not a mathematician. The proofs as written here have very poor presentation, and some valid criticisms have already been explained in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your base cases suffer from high-school-style mute writing. For example:

> $\sum\limits_{i=1}^1 \left(i * i!\right) = \left(1+1\right)! - 1 = 1$
>
> $1 = 1$

This should be something like

> In this case, the claim we must prove is $\sum\limits_{i=1}^1 \left(i * i!\right) = \left(1+1\right)! - 1$.
>
> But this is true, since it boils down to $1 = 1$.

Note the difference: The words explain what the formulas are for. The formulas in themselves aren't a complete argument, as you are reasoning backwards, so the first formula is not in itself obvious but rather follows from the second. (Even if you were reasoning forwards, it would help to insert a word or two.)

Critiquing some minor points:

- No one uses the $*$ sign for multiplication outside of ASCII-only environments. In LaTeX, use "\cdot" ($\cdot$).
- Proofs should start with "*Proof.*" or a similar delineation. (This is, at least, standard since the 1950s or so.)
- Induction steps should start with "*Induction step.*" or a similar delineation.
- "Since" starts a dependent clause, which cannot constitute a whole sentence by itself. Thus, "Since ... The result will be even" should be "Since ..., the result will be even".

In case of doubt, try to look through the eyes of a reader, and imagine the proofs are several times longer and there are many more of them. What changes would improve the reader's experience?

Mathematically, your proofs are correct.